# Simple angular app not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Simple angular app not working

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('SiteController', function($scope)
            {
                $scope.publisher ='sitePoint';
                $scope.type="Web Development";
                $scope.name ="Scope for site controller";
            });
            angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('BookController',function($scope)
            {
                $scope.books=['Jump Start HTML5','Jump Start CSS','Jump Start Responsive Web Design'];
                $scope.name = "Scope for book controller";
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SiteController">
        <span>{{publisher}} excels in {{type}} books</span>
        <div ng-controller="BookController">
            <h3>Some of the popular books from {{publisher}}</h3>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="book in books">
                    {{book}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it because I have declared angular.module twice. Please check the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CUOCHWz4VQrxjdSc6YbH?p=preview)
What did i miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to set the array as a second parameter here `angular.module('myApp',[])`. This syntax means that your are defining a new module.

You can chain the controller like so:

```
        angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('SiteController', function($scope)
        {
            $scope.publisher ='sitePoint';
            $scope.type="Web Development";
            $scope.name ="Scope for site controller";
        })
        .controller('BookController',function($scope)
        {
            $scope.books=['Jump Start HTML5','Jump Start CSS','Jump Start Responsive Web Design'];
            $scope.name = "Scope for book controller";
        });
```

Or, just use the getter `angular.module('myApp')`, without the second argument

```
        angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('SiteController', function($scope)
        {
            $scope.publisher ='sitePoint';
            $scope.type="Web Development";
            $scope.name ="Scope for site controller";
        });
        angular.module('myApp').controller('BookController',function($scope)
        {
            $scope.books=['Jump Start HTML5','Jump Start CSS','Jump Start Responsive Web Design'];
            $scope.name = "Scope for book controller";
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you define the module you need to access it by giving it's name. If you put dependency again it will create another module.. do like this

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('SiteController',
```

and then

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('BookController'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong controller definitions.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
```

Defines new module. If you create controller for current module you have to use:

```
angular.module('myApp')
```

Check this fixed version: http://plnkr.co/edit/xrQ1iaC2531WgxO79LrJ?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Remove `[]` in angular.module the second time.

check : http://plnkr.co/edit/1YSpHQTASimeH42QFZgD?p=preview